# How to find the inverse of a non-singular block matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse, block-matrices

Let $P$ a **3x4** matrix. Augmenting $P$ by one row to make a **4x4** non-singular matrix, denoted $P^{*}$. Now letting $H = P^{*-1}$. What is the result of $PH$?

Comment: Here is how you solve this problem: Try an example or three. Observe the result. Guess the answer, then try to prove it. If you're stuck somewhere in this process, you can come back here and tell us exactly where you're stuck and what you've tried, and we'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N.B. When you post a question, you should provide some context or details about what you have already tried so that it is easier for others to help; I will answer your problem assuming you have done nothing yet.

It may be helpful to break down the product of the two matrices in terms of each row of matrix $P$ being right-multiplied by the matrix $H = P^{*-1}.$ Consider for instance the first row of $P.$ Obviously it is equal to the first row of $P^*.$ We also know that the product of the first row of $P^*$ with $P^{*-1}$ (what is that matrix product?) is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$ You can extend this idea to the other rows. In the end you will get exactly what you expect:

$$\boxed{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}.$$

Hope this helps!